# Visual C++ 2010: Finding out what code/lib requires missing lib

Tags: visual-c++, linker

Short version: MSVC complains about a missing lib, and rather than adding said lib, I would like to remove the source of the dependency.

Motivation: It's an old version of an already linked with library (Boost in this case). I know there's a good chance some of the libs I compiled years ago use this old version, but I can't determine which one. (This is after upgrading/recompiling some of them.) The code base is large enough that I'd rather not try every possible alternative.

It's difficult to google an answer that's relevant (any answers get lost in the noise), so I'm asking here.

Comment: What's the actual text of the complaint?

Answer (score 0):

Try opening those old libs with a text editor and searching for the name of the dependency you want to get rid of. Also make sure that you don't explicitly link in that unwanted dependency in the project properties or with `#pragma comment`.